# How does setting a variable inside while parenthesis work?

Tags: c++

I found a piece of code that I'm debugging and it looks like I don't understand how a while loop works entirely on C++. Take a look:

```
while (_content_len == 0 && _remain_data_size > 0 && (index = onSearchPacketTail(ptr,_remain_data_size)) != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

If I see 10 `hello` on the output, is it true that `onSearchPacketTail` got called 10 times?

I'm asking because there are times when I see lots of `hello` but no `onSearchPacketTail` calls (`onSearchPacketTail` prints `"onSearchPacketTail"` just so I know it has been called).

For me if `hello` is printed 10 times it means that the 3 conditions above were true `10` times which means that `onSearchPacketTail` is being called 10 times.

Comment: It's just a regular assignment that happens to occur within an expression instead of by itself. It will only execute if that logical branch needs to be evaluated due to short-circuit evaluation. If it entered that loop then it must have evaluated, so yeah, ten times.

Comment: If you see hello 10 times then the function was called and returned a valid pointer 10 times. Without seeing that function I can't comment on why you might not see a log from inside it. You should be able to trace into the function with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does setting a variable inside while parenthesis work?

Parentheses work similarly to how they work in mathematics. The operators within parentheses have higher precedence than the operators outside.

> If I see 10 hello on the output, is it true that onSearchPacketTail got called 10 times?

Yes, it is potentially true. No, it is not necessarily true.

If the function returns a null pointer, then there will not be a corresponding "hello", and thus the function will have been called more times.

Otherwise if the function never returns null, and if this is the only part of the program where "hello" is inserted into the output stream, and if this is the only part of the program where `onSearchPacketTail` is called, and the program doesn't terminate prematurely, then the number of each will be equal.